# Elm Http example Http.send call

Tags: elm

I have gone through the documentation of each of the Http functions (arguments and return values) , with little knowledge in function currying I could not understand the function call order from `Http.send` written in `getRandomGif : String -> Cmd Msg` function

Need help in understanding/Expanding the `Http.send` , order in which the function are called. http://elm-lang.org/examples/http

```
-- send : (Result Error a -> msg) -> Request a -> Cmd msg
-- NewGif (Result Http.Error String)
-- get : String -> Decoder a -> Request a

Http.send NewGif (Http.get url decodeGifUrl)
```

Comment: Http.send transforms an Http.Request into a Cmd (of some kind based on a given function).  Elm is also eager.  It'd be called like this: Http.get is called, followed by Http.send, which takes the function and the request and waits.  At some later time, Json.Decode.decodeString is called with decodeGifUrl as an argument, the result is passed via a mechanism internal to Http.send to NewGif, which is a function that is a homonym for a type constructor, and then the result passed to the language runtime to go into your update function.

Comment: Thanks @ArtYerkes , Im trying to understand the lazy vs eager evaluation. Im new to functional programming , so far its good.

Comment: A place where this would differ in a lazy or strict language is this: imagine that the tag function (here NewGif) was a function of one parameter that does a dictionary lookup and and returns another function; in elm, the dictionary lookup is done before the call to Http.send, but in a lazy language, it'd be just before the resulting function is applied to the decoded url.

Comment: Got you, can we rewrite the above code to call the Http get call first and pass the result to send.
But I end up seeing a function returned from http get.

Comment: Are you asking about rewriting it like ```Http.get url decodeGifUrl |> Http.send NewGif``` ?

Comment: Yes and also the first argument of send `NewGif (Result Http.Error String)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138440/discussion-between-art-yerkes-and-anandh).

Comment: It's difficult to grasp a whole concept of Commands and Http requests just from docs. Try going through elm-tutorial.org, [there is a section regarding fetching data](https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en/06-fetching-resources/cover.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Http.send` internally calls Task

Here are the Response from other channels (Slack & Youtube)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDp6UmaA9CM

Elm's task system will eventually invoke the constructor function LoadUser.

Http.send creates a Cmd that we hand to the Elm architecture so it can perform the HTTP request on our behalf. The function we provide to Http.send informs Elm how we want to handle the result when it comes back.

You can see where the Cmd is created here: https://github.com/jfairbank/arch-elm/blob/master/app/src/Profile.elm#L120-L121.

Because we provide a Msg value LoadUser as our function to Http.send, it allows us to respond to LoadUser later in our update function once we have the result back.

Here is where Elm generates a Task: https://github.com/elm-lang/http/blob/master/src/Http.elm#L85-L87. The resultToMessage parameter would be LoadUser in this case.

It might be hard to understand with the function composition operator, but here is where eventually resultToMessage, or LoadUser in this case, gets called in the Task module: https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/5.1.1/src/Task.elm#L237-L243.

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/10/11/elm-chain-http-requests/

Comment: good example of `Http.send` in https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-workshop/blob/solutions/part7/Main.elm#L33